# Send SMS of more than 160 characters in Php using Twilio

Tags: php, yii, twilio-php

I have used twilio yii extention.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/twiliosms/

**but can't send over than 160 characters message.
it will generate this error.**

**The message body exceeds the 160 character limit.**

```
 [*:status] => 400
    [*:info] => 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21605'
    [*:message] => 'The message body exceeds the 160 character limit.'
    [Exception:string] => ''
    [*:code] => 21605
    [*:file] => '/home/nailspolished/public_html/protected/extensions/twilio/Services/Twilio.php'
    [*:line] => 1064
    [Exception:trace] => array
    (
        0 => array
        (
            'file' => '/home/nailspolished/public_html/protected/extensions/twilio/Services/Twilio.php'
            'line' => 1035
            'function' => '_processResponse'
            'class' => 'Services_Twilio'
            'type' => '->'
            'args' => array
            (
                0 => array
                (
                    0 => 400
                    1 => array
                    (
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since'
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
                        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'ETag'
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        'Date' => 'Tue, 02 Jun 2015 10:57:46 GMT'
                        'X-Powered-By' => 'AT-5000'
                        'X-Shenanigans' => 'none'
                        'Content-Length' => '151'
                        'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
                    )
                    2 => '{\"code\": 21605, \"message\": \"The message body exceeds the 160 character limit.\", \"more_info\": \"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21605\", \"status\": 400}'
                )
            )
        )
```

**Twilio APi calling code is :-**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../extensions/twilio/Services/Twilio.php');
        $sid = "******************";
        $token = "******************";
        $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$message = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
                        Yii::app()->params['fromNumber'], // From 
                        Yii::app()->params['countryCode'] . $value['upa_phone_no'], // To
                        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                );
```

sort messages are sending properly but long messages are giving error.
i know we can send messages over than 160 but how, i don't know.

Comment: I didn't have time to take a longer look, but maybe you're using the old API? That one was indeed restricted to 160 characters. The new one (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) uses automatic segmenting, like modern smartphones do, maybe take a look at that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old version of twilio. Use this yii extention, it is latest version of twilio yii extention.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-sms/